# Spring security forces me to logout when use iframe to popup window

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, iframe, spring-boot, spring-security

Firstly, I use the below code to solve the problem witch spring security doesn't  allow us to use iframe.

```
        http.headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
```

Then comes the second problem. Spring security seems to force me to logout when I trigger the popup window using javascript.

There was a similar question posted before, it said that IE restrits the cookies. However, I use safari. Besides, although i add the below code, It still doesn't work.

```
response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

By the way, here is how I use spring security: I make my User entity implements UserDetails and then implement UserDetailService, finally add the below code to my own WebSecurityConfig which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userService());
    }
```

Comment: How do you open that popup? Is the hostname in the URL opened in the popup the same as the hostname in the URL opened in the main browser window?